# Github markdown - formatting code in table cells. Weird behaiviour

Tags: markdown, code-formatting, github-flavored-markdown

I want to mark as `code` some words inside a cell of a markdown table.

By example:

```
| Verb  | Description | Aliases |
| ---   | ---         | ---     |
| `tag` | return the current state tag | `currentState` |`
| `exec`| transact to an output state | `goout` `setOutputState` `gotoOutputState` `nextOutputState` |
| `next` | transact to an input state | `goto` `setInputState` `gotoInputState` `nextInputState` |
| `say` | send a text message to user | `ask` `prompt` |
| `tts` | send a speech message to user | | 
| `asr` | s the incoming message a speech? | |
| `match` | match a pattern/intent | |
| `take` | save the pattern match info  | |
| `slots` | return the slots of a pattern matched | |
| `setvar` | write a dialog unit variable | |
| `getvar` | read a dialog unit variable | |
| `delvar` | delete a dialog unit variable | |
| `delvars` | delete all dialog unit variables | |
| `chatid` | get the current chat id | |
| `setChat` | set the current chat id | |
| `startTimeout` | start a timeout handler | |
| `stopTimeout` | stop the timout handler | |
| `getCounterTimeout` | how many timeout are run? | |
| `setDefaultTimeoutTime` | set the default timeout in msecs | |
| `isSessionActive` | there is a dialog running for current id? | `isDialogActive` |
```

I got weird formatting: some words, as `tag`, don't appear formatted as code. See live demo: https://gist.github.com/solyarisoftware/305008757df96eb71cc1c7d7683fc580

See screenshot:
[image: https://imgur.com/MrHDMJu]

Why? Where I'm wrong?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Refer to this [screen capture](https://imgur.com/MrHDMJu)

Comment: Thx I added the screenshot. Weird isn't it?

Comment: I see no problem at all. Although, as every other row of the table has a gray background, that makes it difficult to discern the slightly different shade of gray background of the code spans. However, all code spans are properly parsed as such. You can always use your browser's "view source" or "inspect" feature and confirm that all code spans are in fact wrapped in `<code>` tags.